# Expressjs cookie-parser prefixes cookie with j:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, redux

In my universal react application I want to set a cookie during SSR and access it on the client side. For this I use react-cookie and cookie-parser (and expressjs).

The issue is that, whenever I set a cookie during SSR, the cookie gets prepended with "j:". I use the react-cookie .plugToRequest(req, res) to add my cookies to the request.

The response from my SSR contains the Set-Cookie header with the prefixed value.

server.jsx

```
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'static')));

  ...

  app.use((req, res) => {
    const client = new ApiClient(req);
    const memoryHistory = createHistory(req.originalUrl);
    const store = createStore(memoryHistory, client);

    cookie.plugToRequest(req, res);

    ...
  });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Regards
Cornel Janssen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, as I only stumbled upon this issue today myself. I provided the answer in a similar question:

[Set cookie in express.js appear j: prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167616/set-cookie-in-express-js-appear-j-prefix)

Basically, it's just a pre-fix so they know the difference between a regular string and a JSON string. Just remove the "j:" manually if you use some other way of parsing it.